# Как плагин kinetic перемещается контент внутри себя?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

Есть вот такой плагин: [jquery.kinetic](https://davetayls.me/jquery.kinetic/)

Изучаю его принцип работы и внутренности.
Но не могу понять  какие свойства он меняет чтобы изменить позиционирование элемента.

отрицательный ***`left`*** не использует. ***`margin`*** тоже.

***Ну по крайней мере `chrome devtools` это не отображает***

Answer (score 1):

Данный плагин использует `scrollLeft` и `scrollTop` контейнера `.wrapper`

Узнать это можно в исходниках в функции `_inputmove`, а также если убрать у контейнера свойство `overflow: hidden;`

```js
$('.wrapper').kinetic();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: solid 5px #000;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.kinetic/jquery.kinetic.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="inner">
    <img src="https://davetayls.me/jquery.kinetic/lib/wembley.jpg" alt="wembley stadium" kasperskylab_antibanner="on">
  </div>
</div>
```